# unable to clear out email field on clone using URL hacking

Tags: administration, configuration, clone

I am creating a button to clone a contact record, however I don't want to clone the email field, therefore I use the following syntax:

> /{!Contact.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}&Email=&account={!Account.Id}

Yet, when I clone the contact the email is populated.

Comment: Try this/{!Contact.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}&Email=''&account={!Account.Id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to pass for the Email field is con15. I use Chrome to inspect the element of the field I want to pass through with a URL hack and then look at the ID.

/{!Contact.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}&con15=

Comment: I guess one of the conNN fields refers to HasOptedOutOfEmail field right?

Comment: any idea what stops a custom field from being set to null?

Comment: con23 looks like the opt out of email field. Custom fields also have IDs that you can use to set values, you'd need to use Chrome to inspect the inputs and get the Id.

Comment: Thx Daniel, how can I use Chrome to inspect?

Comment: Just right click on the field in edit mode and select Inspect Element.